# Mongo read and write same field on the document

Tags: database, mongodb

I want to update `lastUpdatedTimestamp` on a Mongo document **only** if the request contains the same `lastUpdatedTimestamp` value. I can do that in 2 unique transactions:

1. Reading the document from database and comparing it with `lastUpdatedTimestamp` of the request
2. Writing the document to the database with new `lastUpdatedTimestamp`

But the catch is that it is possible for someone else to update the document **after** I have read it hence making the fetched `lastUpdatedTimestamp` in my app invalid

Therefore, it is ideal to be done in 1 transaction where I can compare the request's `lastUpdatedTimestamp` with what's in the database and if it matches, then updated the `lastUpdatedTimestamp` in the database with the new, current date.

Any idea on how this can be achieved in NodeJS / Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand but in pure mongodb you should simply do this:

```
db.collection.update(
 { lastUpdatedTimestamp: <yourLastUpdatedTimestamp> }, // your filter with your provided date to compare with lastUpdatedTimestamp
 { $set: { lastUpdatedTimestamp: new Date()} } // the effective update query
)
```